# Haskell / Wreq - Advice on complicated type signatures for http requests

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, wreq

I'm a Haskell beginner and am currently using [wreq](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/) to make a simple wrapper around an api.  I want to send an `if-modified-since` header if provided with a time.  I am doing so in the following manner.

```
getResponse :: (FormatTime t, Exception e) => File -> Maybe t -> IO (Either e (Response L.ByteString))
getResponse file (Just t) =
  let formattedTime = (B.pack . formatTime defaultTimeLocale rfc822DateFormat) t
      opts = defaults & header "if-modified-since" .~ [formattedTime]
  in try $ getWith opts $ buildUrl file

getResponse file Nothing = try $ (get $ buildUrl file)
```

I noticed that `304 (not modified)` responses are coming back as exceptions so that was my justification for using the `Either` type.  I wanted to provide visibility to errors for people that might use this api wrapper.

Assuming the request is successful, I want to parse the response body into a corresponding type defined in my library. There is a chance deserialization might not work correctly if something changes on the server I'm making requests to so I chose to use the `Maybe` type to account for this.

```
getPayload :: FromJSON b => (Either e (Response L.ByteString)) -> Either e (Maybe b)
getPayload (Left _)  = return Nothing
getPayload (Right a) = return $ fmap Just (^. responseBody) =<< asJSON a
```

The signatures of these functions are starting to seem like an eyesore to me, something in my gut is telling me there is a better way but I am unsure. One thing I did was make another function to put them together with the hopes it would be easier to use.  This is the function I plan on using to create other functions to make more specific requests to individual resources.

```
getResource :: (Exception e, FormatTime t, FromJSON b) => File -> Maybe t -> IO (Either e (Maybe b))
getResource f t =  getPayload <$> (getResponse f t)
```

I now have to deal with 3 layers of structure when dealing with an http request.  `IO`, `Either`, and `Maybe`.  Am I making this too complicated? What can I do to make this less of a pain to work with from a usage and maintainability perspective? How can I improve this?

Comment: Couldn't you flatten `Either e (Maybe b)` into `Either e b`, where the `e` can also carry information about deserialization failures? `Maybe b` is isomorphic to `Either () b`.

Comment: I'd consider using a custom data type `data ResourceResult b = Error e | NotModified | Result b`. Library sum and product types are fine, but are flavorless: they are so generic that they convey no meaning. It's better to use a custom type with proper, evocative names.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation @chi.  I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be quite what you want, but `asJSON` has the return type `m (Response a)`, where `m` is a `MonadThrow`. While `Maybe` is a `MonadThrow` instance, then so is `Either e`. This means that you don't *have* to use `Maybe` in order to handle if anything goes wrong with `asJSON`. You can 'stay' in the `Either` monad instead:

```
getPayload :: FromJSON b => Either SomeException (Response L.ByteString)
                         -> Either SomeException b
getPayload = ((fmap (^. responseBody) . asJSON) =<<)
```

Clearly, this puts an additional constraint on the type of error on the left side, so I'm not sure that this is acceptable. If not, please leave a comment.

Comment: I will try this tonight and get back to you.

Comment: After doing some reading on `MonadThrow` at https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/commercial/content/exceptions-best-practices  It looks like MonadThrow will hide the exception that gets thrown.  I don't want this to happen because if the exception is a 304 response code the consumer will need to know so they can serve what data they have cached.  The idea of using a custom type sounds appealing.

Comment: @NickAcosta Yes, a custom type may be what you want, but it's hardly correct to say that `MonadThrow` will hide the exception. This is true for `Maybe`, because `Nothing` throws away the error cause, but for `Either e`, the exception is right there in the `Left` case, and can be handled with `catch`.

Comment: True. Im going to tinker some more later. Thanks for the time, effort and explanations. Have a good weekend.

Comment: @NickAcosta FWIW, using `MonadThrow` with exceptions *enables* a client to handle exceptions using `catch`, but it doesn't *force* it to do so. OTOH, if you use `Either` or a custom sum type like the one suggested by @chi, then you *force* the client to handle all outcomes of the operation. I tend to lean towards the latter, but it does depend on which goal you're trying to reach.